# Why does the exact string matching brute force algorithm not compare index 1 of P with index 1 of S in the first round of the for?

Tags: algorithms, exact-string-matching

In my ADS course we were given this pseudo code for the "**exact string matching brute force**" algorithm:

```
1 ESM-BF(P, S)
2   m = length(P), n = length(S)
3   k = 0    # number of matches 
4   for j=1,...,n-m+1do
5      i=1
6      while i ≤ m and P[i] == S[j+i] do
7         i = i +1
8      if i == m+1 then
9         k=k+1 
10   return k
```

Given the example pattern
P = **ACGTACT**

and the example string
S = ACGGTACGT**ACGTACT**

Note that indexing starts at 1.

I started to write down with pen and paper what would happen in the first 2 times the for is executed:

```
1 ESM-BF('ACGTACT', 'ACGGTACGTACGTACT')
2   m = 7
3   n = 16
4   for j = 1    # first round
5      i = 1
6      while 1 < 7 AND P[1] == S[1+1] # (--> 'A' == 'C' FALSE skip body)
7      if 1 == 7+1 # (FALSE skip body)
8   for j = 2 # second round in for loop
9      i = 1  
10     while 1 < 7 AND P[1] == S[2+1] # (--> 'A' == 'G' FALSE skip body)
11     if 1 == 7+1 # (FALSE skip body)# back to next for
12   for j = 3 # third round in for loop
13     i = 1         
14     while 1 < 7 AND P[1] == S[3+1] # (--> 'A' == 'G' FALSE skip body)
15     if 1 == 7+1 # (FALSE skip body)# back to next for
```

I see how it would eventually the right match once we reach S[6].

1. Why do we not start comparing P[1] with S[1]?
2. What would happen if the pattern P remained the same but the string was changed to: S = **ACGTACT**ACGGTACGT (- as far as I can understand the algo would just miss the match...)?

Our professor told us that the ESM-BF compares the letters one by one starting from position one in the pattern and string and encouraged us to do it with pen and paper.

I asked some colleagues if they k but they are also confused about it.

What am I missing?

In case I got typos I will add the original from the slides to exclude that I just wrote it down wrong for myself:

[image]

Comment: So I'm wondering why *j* was not initialized with 0. Such that the first for would compare P[1] and S[0+1]...

Comment: Yes, I agree. It seems like a bug to me, perhaps as the result of converting a 0-indexed solution to 1-indexing. The version in CLRS (also 1-indexed) uses `0, ..., N-M` as the range for `j` (which they call `s`).

Comment: @rici Thanks I thought I just completely missed the point of the algo. I could not imagine that the code he gave us was actually wrong. I guess I should tell him about the typo.

Comment: @rici thx for the reference to CLRS I will have a look in that book!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [rici](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/4416/rici) pointed out the bug-free pseudo code is indeed:

```
1 ESM-BF(P, S)
2   m = length(P), n = length(S)
3   k = 0    # number of matches 
4   for j=0,...,n-m do
5      i=1
6      while i ≤ m and P[i] == S[j+i] do
7         i = i +1
8      if i == m+1 then
9         k=k+1 
10   return k
```